# Magento Addto cart lowest price

Tags: price

We have added a product (Rs. 70000) in admin panel and also it show in front end fine. But Some of the customer placed the order with lower price. We are not able to reproducible.Checking with different browser, its working fine for me. This issue faced some customer only. Kindly check and let me know. Please help, this is urgent.

Comment: The information and issue you shared is not sufficient, you need to add screenshots and update if any code customization is done

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have checked with different aspect and find out one issues, if the customer not logged in the website show the correct price, but once logged in website it show different prices (1000Rs). And also i have disabled the Shopping cart price rule and discount coupon also. We are not able to find the solution. In this problem occur only one product. Other product price comes fine.

Comment: Try creating a new product with same configuration as this one's and repeat the scenario where bug comes, and check if bug is coming on the new product also?

Comment: Hi, I have added new product with same configuration, its working fine. But old product have same problem, so we deleted that product. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, just adding it as answer, please confirm if it worked so that if any one else has this problem they may know this alternate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new product with same configuration as this one's and repeat the scenario where bug comes, and check if bug is coming on the new product also?